# Cannot find network path for computer in workgroup of home Windows XP PCs

Tags: windows-xp, network-share, vmware-workstation, bridge

VMWare Workstation 6.5 is running as an app on a Windows Vista 64bit PC host. Thanks to Workstation we have 2 guest machines running: **TerriVM** and **MattVM**  (both of these run **Windows XP SP2**). We are attempting to get virtual networking configured so we can access the files of both of these VM guest systems from other real PCs connected to this home network.

We think we are close but we can't quite get it right... Here is what we've done so far: 
    * On VM Workstation, we set "**Host Virtual Network Mapping**" to use **VMnet0** with the setting "**Bridge to an automatically chosen adapter**".
    * On each VM guest (i.e. using Windows explorer on XP), we rightmouse on the C disk, click "Sharing" tab, set shareName to "C_Disk" and check both boxes labeled "**Share this folder on the network**" and "**Allow network users to change my files**".

Symptoms:

On "**JohnsRealXP**" PC, we go to Windows Explorer, My Computer, Map Network Drive, type into Folder textbox: **\TerriVM\C_Disk** and assign drive letter T. We see all the folders on this shared drive and can open files on them. So that is good.

On same "JohnsRealXP" PC, we go to Windows Explorer, My Computer, *Map
Network Drive*, type into Folder textbox: **\MattVM\C_Disk**
and assign drive letter M. We get a message box "_The network path \mattvm\C_Disk could not be found_".

Alternatively, we type just \mattvm\ into the Folder box and click "Browse" and get a dialog box where we drill down from "Entire Network" to "Microsoft Windows Network" to "**Workgroup**" where both TerriVM and MattVM are listed as computers on the network. Clicking the + sign next to MattVM gives an hourglass and never enables the OK button and I have to cancel.

In summary, I think we've attempted to share both of these virtual machines using the same techniques and connect to them in similar fashion, but one connects properly and the other machine can be seen but no shared resources on it can be accessed. Can anyone suggest something possibly overlooked or something to try? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, a breakthrough on this problem involved turning OFF the Windows Firewall on the share that could not be accessed. A guy from Germany helped me through this:

see this thread on another forum: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/276568